# How do I make the update page display data according to the index and the data can be saved to the database when updating?

Tags: flutter

I'm a new flutter user, so this time I want to explain my problem. I made a data update. When I open the edit data page, the data cannot appear automatically according to the index, then when an update is made, the data that has been entered cannot be saved. Here's the full source code of my flutter lib.

Link source code: https://github.com/azmi1700018002/akm-front

the update form does not appear automatically
[image]

After updating the data cannot be stored in the database
[image]

Comment: Please provide code as formatted text. Screen captures do not allow anyone to copy and paste or search. That GitHub link will be dead in an internet minute, making this Q&A useless.

Answer (score 0):

For starters instead of

```
      @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _nama_debiturController.text;
    _alamatController.text;
    _no_telpController.text;
    _no_ktpController.text;
    _no_selularController.text;
  }
```

do

```
    @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _nama_debiturController.text = nasabah.debiturElement;
    _alamatController.text = nasabah.alamatElement;
    _no_telpController.text = nasabah.telp;
    _no_ktpController.text = nasabah.ktp;
    _no_selularController.text = nasabah.selular;
  }
```

Also dispose them in dispose method (same as initstate)

```
     @override
  void dispose() {
    _controller.dispose();//dispose all of them
    super.dispose();
  }
```

I guess the object values will get updated in the validator of the textfield, so try that if it does not work write in the comments.

Comment: where do I put this code?   @override
  void dispose() {
    _controller.dispose();//dispose all of them
    super.dispose();
  }

Comment: below the code of initState, outside of initState function, that code is for better performance, it won't solve your issue, the code of initState should solve your issue. Do that on edit_nasabah.dart

Comment: I've tried but when I update the data, it can't be saved to the database, is there an error in api.dart and customer_service.dart or in edit_nasabah.dart ?

Comment: do they at least appear in the textfields?

Comment: yes, that's right, it appears in the textfields, but when a data refresh is performed, the updated data is lost and returns to the previous data.

Comment: does the print data in your _update function print correctly? also what is the point of this ? ` nasabah.no_ktp = noktpValue;` in every validator? you are not using in anywhere on update, what is the return of your api call ? `Network().updateData(NasabahService.baseUrl, 'mstdebitur' , data);` ? what does the 
`body['mstdebitur']` return?. Please update your question with these stuff, it is hard to debug this as is and also update the code on git.